# Parent class attribute does not persist in scope

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have an abstract class

```py
from abc import ABC

class StandardClass(ABC):
    _my_table = None

    @classmethod
    def __init__(cls):
        if cls._my_table is not None:
            return
        cls._my_table = pd.read_sql(_my_table_query(), cls._connection)
    # Here some abstract methods
```

I then have two classes that inherit from this abstract class

```py
class ClassFoo(StandardClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class ClassBar(StandardClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

foo = ClassFoo() # Table sql read is performed here as expected
bar = ClassBar() # I would expect the table read to be skipped as it was already performed 
                 # However the table read is performed again even though there should be
                 # only one instance of _my_table (as there should be only one parent class Standard
```

Why do we witness this behaviour? Also, what should I do to obtain the desired behaviour?

Comment: Why are you defining `__init__` as a class method? It's meant to be an instance method. Get rid of the `@classmethod` decoration.

Comment: When you run your code, in `__init__`, `cls` is `ClassFoo` the first time and `ClassBar` the second time.

Comment: If you *want* each class to have its own `_my_table` attribute, define `__init_subclass__` instead. If you want all subclasses to access the same attribute, just define it immediately in the body of `StandardClass` (`_my_table = pd.read_sql(_my_table_query(), ...))` (though you'll need to consider where and how the connection to use as the second argument gets created).

Comment: The second case. I want all classes to access the same variable. However the connection is set in a super parent class. Should I move the establishment of the connection out of the init too?